# Shrink wrap collection of curves to selected mesh

Tags: geometry-nodes

I have tried the shrink wrap modifier successfully to shrink wrap a curve to the selected mesh. Is it possible to shrink wrap a collection of curves? It does not look like its possible using the modifier.

Can this be done with Geometrynodes, currently i have it sort of working but i guess i need it to project rather than snap to the nearest face? In the bottom image you can see the snapped splines do not follow the original shape.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a separate object, use the *collection info* node to pull in your curves, and project them onto another mesh using the *raycast* node.

[image]

Comment: Ah i see what you did. That works perfectly. Thank you :)